# Azure Data Factory - Grab timeout message

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

After a copy activity fails, I'd like to have a specific set of activities to be run if it failed due to a timeout. I can see there is an error message but it's not included within the output json of the copy activity. Is there any way to retrieve this error message and grab the errorCode programatically?

[data factory timeout message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpSjv.png)

I've been trying to grab it via the output of the copy activity but the output below does not have any errors.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljQe8.png)

Is there anyway to use the dynamic content to grab that first errorCode?

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

[image]

**Variables of `Set variable2`**

dynamic content:`@activity('Copy data1').Error.errorCode`

You can also use this dynamic content:`@activity('Copy data1').STATUS`

[image]

**Output of `Set variable2`**(`@activity('Copy data1').Error.errorCode`):

[image]

**Output of `Set variable2`**(`@activity('Copy data1').STATUS`):

[image]

Hope this can help you:).